# Google Client API setAccessToken() before isAccessTokenExpired() results in invalid credentials

Tags: laravel, google-api-client

I am working with the Google Client API in Laravel to allow my users to sync their calendars with Google. Everything works, but the issue I am running into is when their tokens expire they are getting an "Invalid Credentials" error, in order to fix it they have to log out and log back in which I am trying to avoid.

I don't understand why setAccessToken() is to be called before isAccessTokenExpired().

I need to check if the access token is expired before I set it but if I do it this way then isAccessTokenExpired() always returns true.

Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks!

Here is my code:

GoogeServiceController.php

```
class GoogleServiceController extends Controller
{
protected $client;
protected $service;

public function __construct()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(Config::get('google_config.web'));
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $this->client = $client;
    $this->service = $service;
}

public function oauth(Request $request)
{
    if (App::environment('local')) {
        $this->client->setRedirectUri('http://esm.development.com/oauth');
    } else {
        $this->client->setRedirectUri('https://essentialstudiomanager.com/oauth');
    }

    if (is_null($request->user()->refresh_token)) {
        $this->client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
    }

    if (!$request->has('code')) {

        $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
        $filtered_url = filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

        return redirect($filtered_url);

    } else {

        $this->client->authenticate($request->code);

        if (is_null($request->user()->refresh_token)) {
            $refresh_token = $this->client->getRefreshToken();
            $user = $request->user();
            $user->refresh_token = $refresh_token;
            $user->save();
        }

        $request->session()->put('access_token', $this->client->getAccessToken());

        $notification = ['message' => 'Your calendar is now synced with your Google Calendar.', 'alert-type' => 'success'];
        return redirect()->route('home')->with($notification);
    }
}
}
```

GoogleEventController.php

```
public function updateGoogleEvent($request, $event, $title, $description, $start, $end)
{     
    if ($request->session()->has('access_token')) {

        $this->client->setAccessToken(session('access_token'));

        if ($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $this->client->refreshToken($request->user()->refresh_token);
            $request->session()->put('access_token', $this->client->getAccessToken());

            $this->client->setAccessToken(session('access_token'));
        }

    } else {
        return redirect()->route('oauthCallBack');
    }

    $users_calendar = $this->service->calendars->get('primary');

    $get_event = $this->service->events->get('primary', $event->google_event_id);
    $get_event->setSummary($title);
    $get_event->setDescription($description);

    $start_date = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $start_date->setDateTime($start);
    $start_date->setTimeZone($users_calendar->timeZone);
    $get_event->setStart($start_date);


    $end_date = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $end_date->setDateTime($end);
    $end_date->setTimeZone($users_calendar->timeZone);
    $get_event->setEnd($end_date);

    $updatedEvent = $this->service->events->update('primary', $get_event->getId(), $get_event);
}
```

Comment: Alright, I think I found a solution. I created a refresh_token column in the users table and at login, I do a check to see if its null, if it is I force the approval prompt which allows me to get a refresh token. That refresh token is stored and I can now use                                                                  
`$token = fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken(session('access_token')` followed by `$this->client->setAccessToken($token)`

Comment: update to the solution. fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken() didn't work, I ended up using refreshToken($request->user()->refresh_token) and this works.

Comment: How you have solved this? can you please help me i am also stuck into this